# How can I make Google Map markers "come to top" on hover with the JS API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Basically I want to make sure that when a user hovers over on a marker that it is brough to the forefront.  I am developing a hotel search so there is a lot of situations where a lot of hotels are bunched together [think the Strip in Vegas] -- to see a good example of what is happening check out hotels.com [direct link below]

http://www.hotels.com/search/searchmap.html?ar=HomePage::NoSuggest&cd=12-24-10&dd=12-26-10&nr=1&pn=1&r=1&rl=destination:1642852:EXACT_RED:HIGH&so=BEST_SELLER&vc=true&vt=MAP#so=BEST_SELLER&vt=MAP&rl=destination%3A1642852%3AEXACT_RED%3AHIGH&pfm=1&dn=Las+Vegas+(and+vicinity),+Nevada,+United+States&cd=12/24/10&dd=12/26/10&nr=1&pn=1&pfcc=USD&minp=0&maxp=500&ming=0&maxg=5&r=1&cpr=0

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just include an event to set z-index for the parent of the hovered element. I think that's how they are doing it

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 539px; top: 164px; display: block; z-index: 9">
   <span class="map_pin range_mid" style=""></span>   <-- your element
</div>    <--- parent
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Maps API V3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) provides a setZIndex() method for the Marker object. You can call this method to promote the marker to the foreground.

To get it to work, I had to first set a zIndex on each marker as I created it.  I initialized them all to the same value (9, which was arbitrary).  Then in the mouseover event of the hotel name (in a list beside the map), I used the setZIndex method to change the zIndex of that hotel's marker to a higher value than the others (10, again arbitrary).  In the mouseout event, I changed the zIndex back to the original value.